# Why does Allah blind some people and then judge them for being blind?

Tags: justice

This must be important, as it is stated so early in the Quran at Surah 2:7.

Why does Allah blind people to the Truth prior to judging them on their acceptance of the same?

> Allah has set a seal upon their hearts and upon their hearing, and
> over their vision is a veil. And for them is a great punishment.

Also 2:17,

> Their example is that of one who kindled a fire, but when it
> illuminated what was around him, Allah took away their light and left
> them in darkness [so] they could not see.

On my human understanding, this seems unjust on its face.

Obviously, God is the source of all justice, so whatsoever He decrees is Just by definition. Nevertheless, why would He set a certain standard of justice in our hearts and minds and then deploy a different standard of justice vis-a-vis the above verses? Considering one of his famous names is the Merciful, why would he give us a challenge to solve with the tool of rationality which He also gave us and then so clearly traduce it, as above?

Comment: Both verses speak of two (different) examples of people and I'm not sure where you've got the translation from, at least it looks different if not misleading, could you add this information?

Comment: I don't know where I cut and pasted the above but I'm reading from Abdullah Yusuf Ali's translation at the moment, and its functionally the same.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is in verse 2:26 which says Allah (ﷻ) doesn't misguide [e.g., blind] people except those who choose to rebel against Him. Hence, He is misguiding those who choose misguidance.

Likewise, there are verses which say He guides those who seek His path (e.g., 29:69)

In other words, who Allah (ﷻ) guides or misleads is not 'randomized'. Thus, there is nothing unfair or unjust about this, rather it is completely warranted.

Comment: Abdullah Yusuf Ali's translation of 2:26 doesn't really have that flavor. "Allah does not disdain to use the similitude of things ... Those who reject faith say: " What does Allah mean by this similitude?" By it he causes many to stray, ... He does not cause to stray, except those who forsake (the path), -". What I understand by this is those of limited understanding are assured of damnation. So it seems like a reiteration of 2:7 and 2:17 to me. Is there a better translation?

Comment: Actually that is saying the same thing too i.e., when these people choose to *forsake* the path of God, then God causes them to stray.